# How to separate RadioList in a for?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to make an ActiveForm and I need to echo a radioList in a for. My code works but I can select only one button in all the lists. How can I do?

```php
<?php 
  foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $form->field($todoUser[$user->id], 'role')->radioList([0=>'Simple', 1=>'Admin', NULL=>'Non Concerné'])->label($user->username);
  } 
?>
```

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

My code don't totally work, only the 3 last radiobuttons work, the others return nothing.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? i don't understand

Comment: I wanted to make several radioList, each per users. The problem was that only one radio Button can be checked and not one per list. I resolved my problem by assigning a different name at the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I simply added names to my lists like that:

```
<?php
   foreach($users as $user){
      echo $form->field($todoUser[$user->id], 'role')->radioList([0=>'Simple', 1=>'Admin', NULL=>'Non Concerné'],['name'=>'todousers['.$user->id.']'])->label($user->username);
   }
?>
```

And I could to recover them by using this

```
Yii::$app->request->post('todousers')[$user->id]
```